# Get checkboxes in repeater header template

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need to access some checkboxes that are inside the header template of my repeater.

Actually they are outside of it and in the code behind they are accessed using the keyword "this". I cannot change all the code and i must mantain the same logic. The issue is that if i move the checkboxes inside the header of the repeater, i cannot find them using "this".

I've something like this:

```
<div id="containerListNotify" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelRepListNotify" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="iconsHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            <asp:Repeater ID="repListNotify" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepListNotify_ItemCommand"
                                OnItemDataBound="RepListNotify_ItemCreated">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table id="tableCentroMessaggi" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr id="HeaderMessaggi">
                                                <th>
                                                    <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="docFascCol" Text='<%#this.getDocFascColText() %>' />--%>
                                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                                        <button onclick="openCloseDocFascDropdown()" class="dropbtn"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="docFascCol" Text='<%#this.getDocFascColText() %>' /><b class="caret"></b></button>                                              
                                                        <div id="docFascDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="IndexCheckDoc" CssClass="clickableLeftN" Checked="true" runat="server"
                                                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="IndexCkbFilterObject_CheckedChanged" /> 
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="IndexCheckProj" CssClass="clickableLeftN" Checked="true" runat="server"
                                                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="IndexCkbFilterObject_CheckedChanged" />
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li>
                                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="IndexCheckOther" CssClass="clickableLeftN" Checked="true" runat="server"
                                                                        AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="IndexCkbFilterObject_CheckedChanged" />
                                                                </li>
                                                            </ul>                                                              
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
```

The important thing is that i need to access them even in private methods and not only in event methods.

I hope that there is a solution to this. I guess i can use "FindControl".
This .aspx uses a MasterPage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to access Controls that are inside another control like Repeater, GridView etc. you're gonna have to use `FindControl` with and item/row index. You cannot access them directly with `this`

Comment: It's in the Repater HeaderTemplate. I must access them even in private methods in which i don't have the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access Controls that are inside another control like Repeater, GridView etc. you're gonna have to use FindControl with and item/row index. Where you access them does not matter.

```
CheckBox IndexCheckDoc = repListNotify.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("IndexCheckDoc") as CheckBox;
CheckBox IndexCheckProj = repListNotify.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("IndexCheckProj") as CheckBox;
CheckBox IndexCheckOther = repListNotify.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("IndexCheckOther") as CheckBox;
```